# Трансляция звука на микрофон

Tags: java, c++, аудио

Здравствуйте, как можно передать звук, скажем, файл 1.wav, к которому известен путь на микрофон? Т.е заставить систему думать, что в микрофон что-то сказали.

Comment: Укажите операционную систему.

Comment: Операционая систеиа Windows 7 x64